# how to get substring inside string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

hi how to get substring inside string in ruby?

i have string like this :

```
a = "hai my name is tardjo"

b = "this is tardjo"
```

how to get substring tardjo inside string a and b with same way? 
thanks before

Comment: I don't get what you want. If you want to get the string `"tardjo"`, can't you simply have a new variable `"tardjo"`? Or do you want the position on the string that this word starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but: You could use `String#scan` and a regex:

```
a = "hai my name is tardjo"
b = "this is tardjo"

a.scan(/tardjo/)
=> ["tardjo"]

b.scan(/tardjo/)
=> ["tardjo"]
```

**Note**: If you have multiple "tardjo"s in your string, `scan` will return all of them.

If you want the position in the string where the match starts, use the `=~` method instead:

```
a =~ /tardjo/
=> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if either contain tardjo?  You can test it with `include?`

```
a.include?('tardjo')
=> true
```